# JavaScript Arrays : Keep only values that are present an odd number of times, including once

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Hey guys so for example I have an array:

```
myArray[5,4,1,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,1,5,3,2]
```

I'm sorting that array:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

And I want to delete only the two duplicates so the array I want will be

```
[10,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]
```

So i'm using splice:

```
for (var index = 0; index < myArray.length +1; ++myArray) {
  if(myArray[index+1]== myArray[index]) {
    myArray.splice(index);
    myArray.splice[index+1];
  }
}
```

But when I'm pushing more of the of the numbers, the results seem unpredictable
How to do this properly?

To clarify: The purpose is to eliminate the numbers which repeat an even number of times.

Comment: Don't you want 1 to appear once in your output?

Comment: You are modifying the array as you iterate over it; this will cause some erratic behavior. Consider using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead

Comment: Also consider http://underscorejs.org which does exactly this sort of stuff on collections

Comment: ES6 one-liner `Array.from(new Set(myArray));`

Comment: Where does the modulo in your title come into this?

Comment: @danh not really, because 4%2 = 0 and I want only ones, for example 3%2=1.

Comment: @Hamms I'm checking the filter, It's seems to look good

Comment: @JaredSmith Can I filter using this?

Comment: @Rafalsonn sorry I misunderstood the question, my one-liner removes *all* duplicates by converting the array to a mathematical Set and back to an array.

Comment: @TecBrat I think the modulo is the solution, because I wan't to have only the values which a number of repeats is (a number)%2=1

Comment: You want all values that show up an odd number of times, including once?

Comment: @danh Yes, that's correct

Comment: @TecBrat yes, so If the item's repetition is 11 times, I want it, but if it's 10 times I don't

Comment: "it's modulo by 2" doesn't really make any grammatical sense, which I think is why a lot of people are getting confused.

Comment: @recursive. I think it was a language issue. See my edits.

Comment: No need to specify "including once", as 1 is odd anyway.

Comment: @TecBrat Great, that it's what I mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an ECMAScript2015 solution:

```js
var myArray = [5,4,1,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,1,5,3,2];
var count = myArray.reduce((count, num) => 
                           (count[num] = (count[num] || 0) + 1, count), {});
myArray = Object.keys(count).filter(num => count[num] % 2).map(Number);
console.log(myArray);
```

The count variable is an object of which the properties are the numbers in the original array. The value for each of these properties is the number of occurrences of that number in the original array.

The keys are then iterated to get only those into the final array that have a value (i.e. occurrences) that is odd. As object properties are iterated in numerical order (when numerical), the result is automatically sorted numerically.

#### About your code:

The `for` loop you have, has some issues:

```
for (var index = 0; index < myArray.length +1; ++myArray) {
  if(myArray[index+1]== myArray[index]) {
    myArray.splice(index);
    myArray.splice[index+1];
  }
}
```

- Certainly you don't want to increment `myArray`, but `index`.
- The boundary condition should not be `length+1` but `length-1` as in the body you have `myArray[index+1]` and don't want to go out of bounds there.
- But more importantly, doing `splice` in your `for` loop will make the elements shift position, and as you then still increment `index`, you will skip elements.

In short, you should not use `splice` in such a loop. You can solve this by going in the reverse direction, and start at the end of the array working towards the beginning.

But the above proposed code does not have this problem and also saves you the step of sorting.

Comment: It's working, and I see it now I've made many mistakes in my code, thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another method, which checks for an odd number of elements by subtracting the **indexOf** the key from the **lastIndexOf** the key after sorting:

```js
var myArray = [5,4,1,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,1,5,3,2];

var result = myArray.sort().filter(function(key, idx) {
  return myArray.indexOf(key) === idx && //handle first instance only
         (myArray.lastIndexOf(key) - myArray.indexOf(key)) % 2 === 0;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two `reduce` and `Object.keys()`. First add values to object and then check each value with `% 2` and add to array.

```js
var myArray = [5,4,1,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,1,5,3,2];
var obj = myArray.reduce(function(o, e) {
  o[e] = (o[e] || 0)+1;
  return o;
}, {})

var result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(obj[e] % 2) r.push(Number(e));
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Great solution, now I see how to solve problems like that, thank You.